# Preventing Deletion with django-simple-history

Tags: django-simple-history

I started using django-simple-history in order to keep the history but when I delete an object (from admin page at least) I notice that it is gone for good.

I suppose I could create tags and "hide" objects instead of deleting in my views but would be nice if there is an easier way with django-simple-history, which would also cover admin operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When objects are deleted, that deletion is also recorded in history. The object does not exist anymore, but its history is safe.

If you browse your database, you should find a table named:

```
[app_name]_history[model_name]
```

It contains a line with the last state of the object. That line also contains additional columns: `history_id, history_change_reason, history_date, history_type`. For a deletion, `history_type` will be set to "-" (minus sign).

Knowing that, it is possible to revert a deletion programmatically, but not through the Django Admin. Have a look at django-simple-history documentation for details on how to do it programmatically.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I can't find anything in the django-simple-history documentation on reverting deletions.

Comment: Does this section help: https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/querying_history.html#reverting-the-model

Comment: Yes it does.  I didn't find explicit instructions on reverting deletions, but it's just a matter of filtering your history model object for the .latest() (assuming delete is the most recent action) and/or the "-" in history_type which equals a delete, then reverting using the normal method as described.  Gotta say, django-simple-history is pretty awesome.

Comment: Update to my comment above.  You can restore changes to a model instance, but not the deletion of a model instance itself.  The history is in indeed there, but that history shows you when and who deleted the model instance.  It does not permit reversion to a pre-deleted state. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55160348/1901391